# Разный ответ на запрос баланса

Tags: телефония

При запросе баланса с помощью USSD команды Мегафон выдает разные результаты, на запрос введенный руками `*100#` и на запрос выполняемый программно `'at+cusd=1,*100#,15\r\n'`. Баланс всегда разный на пару рублей, в моем случае это крайне критично. Такая проблема только с Мегафоном.

Что может подсказать?

**Обновление**

Есть прошивка для модема, написанная на Lua. В ней есть функция проверки баланса на разных операторах связи. Запрос выполняется USSD командой. Поскольку метки USSD нет, а я еще не обладаю правами создания новой метки, ближайшая метка была Телефония.

Comment: @Raaur, Подскажите, как ваш вопрос относится к программированию? Что именно не получается реализовать?

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, походу только с Мегафон'ом. Предполагаю, что у них базы разные и обновления происходят с задержкой.

Comment: А вот у них есть еще такая команда, как 102, тоже проверяет баланс.  Но, насколько я понял, не во всех регионах. К примеру, в Поволжском регионе нет такой команды, а в остальных может, кто знает?